# Проблема с длинными числами в алгоритме DSA на C#

Tags: c#

Мне нужно посчитать число 2 в степени `(p-1)/q` и найти остаток деления результата на `p`, где `p` имеет размерность 1024 бита, а q 128, тип данных чисел - `BigInteger`. Я пытался считать циклом `for`, но он оказывается настолько тяжёлым что программа виснет. Методы `Math.Pow` и `BigInteger.Pow` не принимают аргумент степени типа `BigInteger`, других я не знаю.

Comment: попробуйте рефлексию использовать